# 78RPM 1900's records - is there more in the high end signal than humans hear, and could ML extract it?

Tags: audio, machine-learning, denoising

Consider some record with Enrico Caruso singing, anno 1904 or so. Back then, records did not employ pre-distortion such as with RIAA curve to then later, during playback, invert the curve, to get a normal amount of high (and low) end and reduce the hissing sound from the needle scratching the material.

So, it's usually thought of as "there's only noise, so roll off the high end strongly and have something listenable" - *perhaps* lacking a bit more higher end (or mids) than could be in the signal. But since humans aren't good at hearing things in midst of close frequencies of similar amplitude, which is used in lossy compression such as MP3, perhaps there actually is a little bit more buried in all the hiss which we can't hear - but perhaps software could extract it, remove the hiss without overly dampening the sound quality?

Could Machine-Learning achieve that, is there even something in existence already?
I searched for examples on youtube that someone would certainly have put up there if it existed - one does see AI-based image upscales of very early movies etc... but not found anything.

I did not post this on AI stackexchangce because it touches both areas, but probably more DSP due to theory of what can be in a signal (despite us not hearing it), etc.
I realise all the "ancient" mechanical equipment probably *was* very band limiting, but then again, the replay gear may have also taken more than there is present on the record, and commercial processing for sale on e.g. CDs in the past always used blunt filters to just roll of higher frequencies.

Comment: Study the involved gear they used at that times (what was possible). A decade ago I ran test to find out if there are content > 20kHz on vinyl recordings by recording vinyl using high resolution (24-bit/192kHz), filtered out below 20kHz audio with a steep HPF, saved > 20kHz data, dropped this new file samplerate to 1/4 of the original by just editing the samplerate info of WAV file header (i.e. brought the hf area to hearable range). Do not normalize the recording at any point. Example of content above 20kHz: https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=106205.0;attach=8663;image

Comment: Spectogram plots: Original 24/192 recording: https://i.postimg.cc/W4WfKmHX/24192-no-normaliz-192k.png , filtered : https://i.postimg.cc/zB42Dz5h/24192-no-normaliz-hf-192k.png , down sampled : https://i.postimg.cc/hjX3qzFg/24192-no-normaliz-hf-48k.png